# How can i reset the position of the BufferedReader?

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

iam using BufferedReader to Read lines from file. when i read all the lines from the file i want to reread the file again from the beginning, how can i do so? the `BufferedReader.mark()` and `BufferedReader.reset()`  are not working properly.this is my code

```
FileReader fR = new FileReader(this.sTargetPath);
            final BufferedReader vcfBuffer = new BufferedReader(fR);
        //  vcfBuffer.mark(0);
                Boolean nextLine = true;
                while (nextLine) {
                    try {
                        String line = vcfBuffer.readLine();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        nextLine = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            vcfBuffer.reset();
```

How can i reset the BufferedREader Position? thanks for helping

Comment: Create a new buffered reader object again.. Or use `RandomAccesFile` `seek(0)` method.

Comment: there is no other way than to create another reader? i dont think this is good idea, it works but it is not efficient right?

Comment: I think you can create a mark right before you read the first line, then you can later use the method reset() to return to that point, I havent tried this before though.

Comment: A `BufferedReader` has its "mark" invalidated if you read more than the internal buffer can hold. Either read & store the contents of the file as a `char[]` array and use a `CharArrayReader` instead of `FileReader` as the input to your `BufferedReader` - or increase the size of the buffer.

Comment: using BufferedReader is always fast, but takes little more memory. Its OK as long as it works. I dont know any way to set to start a InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc of mark()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark%28int%29) says: (emphasis mine):

> Parameters:
>
> readAheadLimit - **Limit on the number of characters that may be read while still preserving the mark. An attempt to reset the stream
>   after reading characters up to this limit or beyond may fail.** A limit
>   value larger than the size of the input buffer will cause a new buffer
>   to be allocated whose size is no smaller than limit. Therefore large
>   values should be used with care.

If you invoke it with 0 as argument, as soon as you read one byte more from the reader, it might be impossible to reset.

The solution is to call the mark method with the length of the file as argument. But of course, this will lead to reading the whole file in an in-memory buffer. If you don't want that, close your reader and reopen a new BufferedReader.